# Delay/Hold a text in opencv succesive frames

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

My code snippet looks like this: I want to delay the text in the below inbuilt OpenCV function "cvPutText" so that it appears in the succesive 5or 6 frames.

**cvPutText (frame_OPENCV,"STRING",cvPoint(60,40),&font,cvScalar(0,0,255,0));**

How to display the STRING in 5 successive frames?

Comment: I think there's no other way than to add it manually on each frame. Just make an index to count how many frames you have displayed with the text, then pause as much as you want or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the QT backend:

the function displayOverlay() allows you to display some text over the image for a given time interval, without modifying the source image

[displayOverlay()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html?highlight=text#void%20displayOverlay%28const%20string&%20name,%20const%20string&%20text,%20int%20delay%29)